# Substitution v/s elimination

Tags: organic-chemistry

For SN2 pathway we use an strong nucleophile (OH-,CN-) so they can easily substitute X(halogen) group from rear side.

While for elimination bimolecular reactions we use a strong conjugated base (RCH2O- or alc.kOH) so that it takes proton from carbon  near by to halogen,thus forming an alkene .

While in my text book I had found
[image]

I was agree with first diagram stating that bulky group will more tend to show elimination rather that substitution but in second diagram they show ethoxide ion giving substitution reaction .

To which I disagree, According to me it be should also show elimination reaction.

Comment: Welcome to CH SE site! 

Note that using photos/screenshots of text instead of typing text itself is highly discouraged.  The image text content cannot be indexed nor searched for, nor can be reused in answers.  Specifically handwritten scripts can be difficult to decipher.  Consider  copy/pasting or rewriting of at least essential parts. 

Suitable formatting can be done according to [formatting math/chem expressions/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).

Comment: @Poutnik I have issue with the diagram  part of it . Text is only for giving context of what I'm talking about.

Comment: I see. It has looked for me like the essential part of the question.

Comment: If would like to know what you take on this problem.

Comment: I would think you get a mixture of both, but I would be more biased towards the elimination than substitution.

Comment: So ,as per concept I should sum up that in either of the situation elimination should be major product .

Comment: The right scenario probably depends a lot on solvent. My guess is that someone probably carried out this study in the 30s and there's likely a reference.

Comment: Check out the Williamson ether synthesis, conditions [and reactants] can be adjusted to some extent to affect the elimination substitution rates.

Answer (score 1):

I think both elimination and substitution reaction will occur any of them can dominate cos ethoxide ion is a strong nucleophile and in presence of a alcohol as a solvent. So the reaction which will dominate depends upon solvent which is not mentioned. Moreover it is also a 2°alkyl halide so solvent is much more important factor.